# What is the type of "detail" in this following js code to typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, addeventlistener

I am new to typescript. I want to convert this js code to ts.

```
acceptEvent.addEventListener( "accept", ({ detail: { hour, minutes, type } }) =>
this.time = `${hour}:${minutes} ${type}`
);
```

The problem I am having is with the detail part. What is the correct type of argument in the listener function? Typescript gives me the following error :

> Property 'detail' does not exist on type 'Event'

Comment: I've tried it before. But it is not working

Comment: If that is the case, you should add what you've tried to your question and describe how it fails.

Comment: I am trying to implement the accept event from https://pglejzer.github.io/timepicker-ui-docs/ . the code i have given tries what is the type of the detail in the addevent listener parameter

Comment: Regarding the error message the OP needs to make the type-checking process aware of handling a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/detail) instead of `Event`.

Comment: how is the value of hour, minutes and type coming to the function in js ? @PeterSeliger

Comment: @iamneaz ... it's part of the custom `AcceptEvent`'s `details` object and thus implemented and documented by the library's owner/vendor (scrolling to the very bottom of the above provided timepicker-ui-docs documentation).